# Jest ignorando especificações do package.json

Tags: react, jest

Estou implementando testes em minha aplicação web em react com o jest. Como ele foi iniciado com o "create-react-app" foi fácil configurar o ambiente. 
Mas por algum motivo o jest parece ignorar especificações do package.json...

```
{
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom":[
      "src/**/*.{js,sx}",
      "!src/index.js",
      "!src/BooksAPI.js"
    ],
    "snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"]
  }
...
}
```

Embora eu tenha acrescentado ao collectCoverageFrom para ignorar os arquivos index e BooksAPI eles persistem quando rodo testes com a flag --coverage ativa. Alem disso, apesar de eu declarar especificamente que quero usar o serializer do pacote 'enzyme-to-json' o snapshot permanece como o padrão do jest.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe o que possivelmente eu poderia estar fazendo errado? Já chequei a digitação com atenção e acho que está correto. Segue o link do projeto caso seja necessário: https://github.com/Matheusbafutto/reactnd-project-myreads-starter

Comment: Podes ter também `collectCoverage: true`. Já testaste essa configuração?

Comment: Já testei mas não chegou a resolver...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parece que era um problema no próprio react-scripts. O erro ocorria quando usava a versão 0.9.x do react-scripts. Ao fazer o update para a versão 1.0.13 o problema desapareceu.